# How to map all requests to a subdirectory using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this structure:

```
root
-web
-- .htaccess
-- index.html
-- robots.txt
-.htaccess
```

My document root is **root** dir.
Contents of /root/.htaccess are:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule    ^$ web/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, both requests /robots.txt and /web/robots.txt point to a single file, i.e. there is a copy of a whole website under the /web/.

How can I make such a rule in the .htaccess file so /web/robots.txt will point to /web/web/robots.txt (and show 404)? I need to make only /robots.txt work.

Solution must be using .htaccess only.

(The problem is not about robots.txt file, it's just an example)

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have another `/web/` folder inside `/web/` also?

Comment: No, I don't. I mean if /web/robots.txt will point to /web/web/robots.txt, it will not find it and show 404, and that is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your root .htaccess like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on

    # otherwise route /foobar to /web/foobar
    RewriteRule ^((?!web/).*)$ web/$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

This will avoid adding `web/` if request already has it.

Inside `/web/.htaccess` have this rule as **first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

# show 404 for direct requests to /web    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /web [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. /web/robots.txt still point to /web/robots.txt. It seems that if file exists, apache doesn't look in .htaccess for instructions.

Comment: Didn't get it. ` /web/robots.txt` is supposed to be fetched from ` `/web/robots.txt` only right? May be I am not getting your requirement clearly

Comment: no, /robots.txt must point to /web/robots.txt, and /web/robots.txt must point to /web/web/robots.txt.

Comment: `/robots.txt` must point to `/web/robots.txt` is fine and rule is already doing it but this is the part I don't get: **`/web/robots.txt` must point to `/web/web/robots.txt`**  If there is no path called `/web/web/` then what is point of routing to it?

Comment: Now /web/robots.txt is pointing to /web/robots.txt as well, so it is a copy of whole website under /web/, and it as a huge problem. I need to make request /web/robots.txt show 404 because there is no /web/web/robots.txt on the server.

Comment: It still doesn't work. It seems that Apache looks for /web/robots.txt file, finds it, and doesn't look for any instructions in .htaccess after that. Is it possible? Maybe some kind of Apache configuration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72391/discussion-between-anubhava-and-vladimir-mikhaylovskiy).